# 2D limit with exponentials

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, exponential-function

I want to show that

$$\lim_{(a,b)\to (0,0)^+} \frac{ 1-e^{-(a+b)} }{ (1-e^{-a})(1-e^{-b}) } - \frac 1a - \frac 1b =0 $$

where the + means that the limit is taken only with respect to paths in the nonnegative quarter .(i.e, a,b are non-negative)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want $a$, $b>0$ for this to make sense. Now,
$$\frac1{1-e^{-a}}=\frac{1}{a-a^2/2+\cdots}=\frac1a+\frac12+O(a)$$
as $a\to0^+$. Therefore you can replace your limit by the limit of
$$\frac{1-e^{-a-b}}{(1-e^{-a})(1-e^{-b})}-\frac1{1-e^{-a}}-\frac1{1-e^{-b}}+1
$$
as $(a,b)\to(0,0)^+$. Let $x=e^{-a}$, $y=e^{-b}$. Then this equals
$$\frac{1-xy}{(1-x)(1-y)}-\frac1{1-x}-\frac1{1-y}+1=
\frac{1-xy-(1-y)-(1-x)+(1-x)(1-y)}{(1-x)(1-y)}=0.$$